# sql double join orderby

Tags: mysql

Currently i have a table like below

```
Table1
   hTeam-----aTeam-------date---

    3----------5 ------2012/01/01

    4 -------- 7 ------2012/01/04

    2 -------- 8 ------2012/01/05
```

i have a use a double inner join to get the values of id1 and id2, the code is below:

```
    Select hTeam As col1,
    aTeam As col2
    From fixtures as t
    Join team as d1 On ( d1.teamid = t.col1)
    Join team as d2 On ( d2.team = t.col2 )
```

This creates a table like this

```
Table2
    hTeam-------------aTeam--

    Teamname1-------TeamName1 

    TeamName2 ----- Teamname2 

    TeamName3 ----- TeamName4
```

I don't want the team name to be matches i.e. I want a exact replicate of table1 although with the team names like below

```
Table3
    hTeam-------------aTeam--

    Teamname3-------TeamName5 

    TeamName4 ----- Teamname7 

    TeamName2 ----- TeamName8
```

Hope i explained this well enough.

Comment: What are your results ordered by in the original result set (which goes 3 - 4 - 2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what the problem is, as you appear to pretty much have it:

```sql
SELECT h.name AS home, a.name AS away
FROM   fixtures AS f
  JOIN team AS h ON h.teamid = f.hTeam
  JOIN team AS a ON a.teamid = f.aTeam
```

Comment: I believe he wants to prevent the results being reordered by the query.